# Adjusting Gear Actuation

Tags: shimano, gears

I recently brought a second hand bike with Shimano Deore gears on it and  when I switch up a gear on the chain-ring it requires a significant amount of actuation pressure on the 'flappy' paddle  (almost reaches travel limit before changes).

I was wondering how I should adjust this to reduce actuation pressure?

Comment: You should have a knowledgeable friend or a bike shop check out the bike to see if it's basically set up right.

Comment: I'm not sure how similar the actuation methods of brifters are to indexed mountain bike shifters, but I had similar symptoms on our tandem when we got it. There was no "ratcheting" when upshifting on the front derailer, it took almost full travel to make a one-ring shift. My almost-LBS suggested flooding the shifter with a thin chain lubricant in a blue aerosol can (sorry, I don't have the can nearby) to see if solvent/carrier in the lube would free up the ratchet pawls. It worked and now I can make short strokes to shift or trim the derailer.

Comment: The stuff in the blue can is Finish Line [1-Step](http://www.finishlineusa.com/products/chain-lubricants/1-step-cleaner-and-lubricant).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're comparing the effort to, but typically the front derailleur requires more cable pull to actuate, in comparison to shifting in the rear.

[Adjusting Shimano Front Derailleurs](https://youtu.be/tfBiXgf8JxI)

[Adjusting Shimano Rear Derailleurs](https://youtu.be/wQncKmddahk)

It could be that you need a bit of slack removed from the cable, but without photos, it's hard to say.

[Front shifting explained](https://youtu.be/Ea03ChN-7Vg)

Comment: Can you please edit this to answer the question - link-only answers are poor but once the links break they're completely useless.